# How do i delete a key from my txt file everytime the user presses backspace?

Tags: python-3.7, backspace, keylogger, pynput

everytime i press the backspace key i want remove the last key from the my txt file, i tried using find('backspace') to delete but doesn't seem to work

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
keys = []

def on_pressed(key):
    global count, keys
    keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    if count > 0:
        count = 0
        writing_to_file(keys)
        keys = []

def writing_to_file(keys):
    with open('C:\\zzzLoggingEverything\\Logger.txt', 'a') as f:
        for key in keys:
            newkey = str(key).replace("'", "")

            if newkey.find('backspace') > 0:
                newkey[:-1]
            elif newkey.find('space') > 0:
                f.write(' ')
            elif newkey.find('enter') > 0:
                f.write('\n')
            elif newkey.find('Key') == -1:
                f.write(newkey)

def on_released(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_pressed, on_release=on_released) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Are you writing streaming on file ?

Comment: A big mistake here is use ``'a'`` on on open file, only add.

Comment: Yea i am updating it every key that is pressed.
should i change it to 'w', will that let me delete a key from my text?

Comment: I doesn't recommend do what are you trying to do, for example if you are trying make a notepad, the notepad doesn't save info every time you insert characters, i recommend do that  how i answer you.

Comment: how should i save the keys if not notepad then?

Comment: For what exactly you want to do this ?

Comment: to record everything i type in my keyboard as accurately as possible

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried, only make operations on a string and when you finish, add all string to file ? For example when backspace, remove the ultimate character of string every time.

Comment: no, how would i do that? do i just make a list that gets every key and then adds into the txt file everytime i press enter?